# Null reference exception when calling parent form from user control in C# WinForms App

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls, parent, nullreferenceexception

I have a peculiar problem in a C# WinForms app in which sever user controls are used within a parent Form.
Here’s the code for the problem user control:

```
private void LoadMCQuestionScreen(clsQuestion MCQuestion)
{
    ucMultiChoiceQuestion MCQuestionScreen = new  ucMultiChoiceQuestion(MCQuestion, Players, glbintQuestionIndex,
                                                                                glbblTransYesOrNo,
                                                                                lstTransList.ElementAt(glbintQuestionIndex));

   MCQuestionScreen.Parent = this;
   MCQuestionScreen.Show();
    }
```

Here’s the block of code for that user control where the crash occurs:

```
private void QuestionIsAnswered(bool TimeExpired)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("Points: " + glbintPoints.ToString(), "Info...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //Create a reference to frmMain.

    if (TimeExpired == true)
        glbblAnsweredCorrectly = false;

        frmGame form1 = (frmGame)this.Parent;
        **form1.LoadAnswerResponseScreen(glbblAnsweredCorrectly, glbstrAnsweringPlayer);**
    spTickTock.Stop();
    MCPlayer.Dispose();
    tmrMCTimer.Dispose();
    if (pbQuestionImage.Image != null)
    pbQuestionImage.Image.Dispose();
    this.Dispose();
}
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line in bold –

> “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”

In that line, form1 is null. This method and the user control `MCQuestionScreen` will have already been disposed when the crash occurs. 
I’ve tried this code at top of the “`LoadMCQuestionScreen`” method:

```
foreach (UserControl uctrl in this.Controls)
         uctrl.Dispose();
```

That code doesn’t work and after 2 days I still can’t pin down the actual source of the problem.

Comment: You can't "dispose a method".  You need to find out why the method is getting called after the UC is disposed.  Use the debugger's Call Stack window, the one whose content you should have posted in your question.  Crystal ball says it is a timer that makes it run, one you forgot to stop.

Comment: Presumably `this.Parent` in the `QuestionIsAnswered` method is null? Step through your code to determine at which point the `Parent` property on the `ucMultiChoiceQuestion` instance is, and is not null. It's either somehow not being set in the first place, or is being un-set by something.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means you tried to reference an object which has not been instantiated.  You might have to do this:  frmGame form1 = **new** (frmGame)this.Parent;

or it could be somewhere else in your code that we do not see.